# Include a custom field in mysql query

Tags: php, custom-field, query, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
            city_latitude.post_id,
            city_latitude.meta_value as charity_latitude,
            city_longitude.meta_value as charity_longitude,
            ((ACOS(SIN(%f * PI() / 180) * SIN(city_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) + COS(%f * PI() / 180) * COS(city_latitude.meta_value * PI() / 180) * COS((%f - city_longitude.meta_value) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance,
            FxFfekP0_posts.post_title
            FROM 
            FxFfekP0_postmeta AS city_latitude
            LEFT JOIN FxFfekP0_postmeta as city_longitude ON city_latitude.post_id = city_longitude.post_id
            INNER JOIN FxFfekP0_posts ON FxFfekP0_posts.ID = city_latitude.post_id
            WHERE city_latitude.meta_key = 'latitude' AND city_longitude.meta_key = 'longitude'
            HAVING distance < %d
            ORDER BY distance ASC
```

How do I add to this query and include a custom field of `charity_name` as a column? I'm having a hard time with this one...

Comment: What is the `city_latitude`? This looks to be more of an SQL question than a WordPress question

Comment: Why don't you use meta query? Read this article please, for more information https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, it is a MySQL question, but it's relating to the WordPress database schema.

Comment: That is true but somebody with only knowledge of SQL could answer this question given the database table in question, you're more likely to find answers elsewhere, stack overflow might be more productive ( the basic yard stick is would the question require any WordPress specific knowledge to answer? )